# Django request.user.is_authenticated() not working when sending form data

Tags: django, forms-authentication, registration

i've a probelem with the request.user.is_authenticated()
this the view.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from forms import RegistrationForm

def ContributorRegistration(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        '''if user is logged in -> show profile'''
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        '''if post, check the data'''
        form = ContributorRegistration(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ''' if form is valid, save the data'''
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],email = form.cleaned_data['email'], password= form.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.save()
            contributor = user.get_profile()
            contributor.location = form.cleaned_data['location']
            contributor.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('profile.html')
        else:
            '''form not valid-> errors'''
            return render_to_response('register.html',{'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else: 
        '''method is not a post and user is not logged, show the registration form'''
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context={'form':form}
        return render_to_response('register.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

basically, 
if the user is logged in then the profile.html is shown: **OK**
if the user is not logged in and he's not posting data then the form is shown: **OK**
when i submit the data from the form i receive back this error:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/register/
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'user'
Exception Location: /Users/me/sw/DjangoProjects/earth/views.py in ContributorRegistration, line 9
```

where line 9 is `if request.user.is_authenticated():`
so seems that the `request` does not have the `user` object when submitting the form data. 
how can i solve?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're filling your own view function with the request.POST data as if it was the form.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    '''if post, check the data'''
    form = ContributorRegistration(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
```

Should be

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    '''if post, check the data'''
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
```

In order to have access to `request.user` object, you need to have the User authentication middleware installed in your application. To do this (extremely easy), do the following:

Go to your `settings.py` and add `'django.contrib.auth'` and `'django.contrib.contenttypes'` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` tupple.

You are very likely to require a syncdb command for it to be fully installed (you need some database tables for user authentication).

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

And that should make it work.

Comment: wait. the request.user works in the two cases (when i check if user is logged in or if he do a GET of the page) but not when i post data from the form.

Comment: the point is that, when i post data, the request values change to the form data. so no user object. 
correct?

Comment: Yes. Let me think about this. For now, you still have one error (check edit I'm about to make on answer)

Comment: well, the edit you suggest is not correct, or at least it does not work. this is what i get if i change: `'RegistrationForm' object has no attribute 'clean_data'`

Comment: Ok, you were right. my fault. right now i've another problem. the `password_control` raise an error `Exception Type: KeyError`

this is the code http://pastie.org/4909985

Comment: Can you provide the full error? And probably the template, if that's ok.

Comment: thx for the help.
here it's the full error http://pastie.org/4910154 actually it does not says much.
Here the template: http://pastie.org/4910158 and the webpage compiled:http://pastie.org/4910165

Comment: Back from eating. I haven't used Django for over a year, but I believe your problem is that password_control hasn't been cleaned by the time clean_password method is called. When two fields depend on each other, the recommendation is to use clean() method instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Comment: i guess it's because i create the Requester object straight as the user is created (changing the AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE) and the field is still empty during the creation. 
i removed the auto creation and add them manually when i receive the data from the form, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just me or is the name of your form the same as your view function `ContributorRegistration`?

Perhaps you've made a typo.

Comment: form is `class RegistrationForm(BootstrapForm):`
view is `def ContributorRegistration(request):`

Comment: And that't the correction I did. The form (when it is not a POST request) to be shown using is "RegistrationForm".